# Prepared Statement using VB.NET, MySql, and OleDbConnection

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am editing some VB.NET code that looks similar to this:

```
    Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(mySqlConn)
    objConn.Open()
    dim SearchSQL = "EXEC dbo.SearchActivities N'" & LoggedUser.Text & "', N'" & searchAFEs.Text & "'"
    Dim objCmd5 As New OleDbCommand(SearchSQL, objConn)
    Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader
    dg2.DataSource = objCmd5.ExecuteReader()
    dg2.DataBind()
    objConn.Close()
```

That guy is gone, and this is my code now.

I want to clean it up to look more like the style I prefer:

```
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("EXEC dbo.SearchActivities @value1, @value2", New OleDbConnection(mySqlConn))
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value1", LoggedUser.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value2", searchAFEs.Text)
      cmd.Prepare()
      cmd.Connection.Open()
      dg2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      dg2.DataBind()
      cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Using
```

What I cannot seem to find documentation on is how to specify the parameter names, what is allowed and what format to put those in.

Microsoft SQL Server, which I am most familiar with, would use "value1" and "value2", but I am seeing various ways that MySQL expects these named parameters to be in. Some use "?" to denote fields, but then how does the code know what value I am assigning?

Is it simply consecutive and it ignores the name that is supplied (like Microsoft Access)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("EXEC dbo.SearchActivities @value1 = ?, @value2 = ?", New OleDbConnection(mySqlConn))
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", LoggedUser.Text)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", searchAFEs.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. That I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your changes are working in the right direction as this help help to prevent sql injection attacks but:

`OleDbCommand` and `OdbcCommand` do not support named parameters, and use `?` placeholders instead.

Something like this:

```
Dim SearchSQL = "EXEC dbo.SearchActivities ?, ?"
```

Important note that you have to specify the parameters in the order they appear in your command

Comment: If I have `?` in the statement, then how do I add the parameters? Is it first come, first serve?

Comment: What about formatting? The original VB code uses `"...N'" & LoggedUser.Text & "', ..."` would I write `"...N'?', ..."` or `"...?, ..."`? Do you understand what I am asking?